# React dropdown select

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying to get my dropdown to allow me to select one of the options, but it ain't happening. Cannot find any further documentation on if I needed more for this function. Not sure why I cannot select. My code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Media,
  Dropdown,
  DropdownToggle,
  DropdownMenu,
  DropdownItem,
  Button,
} from 'reactstrap';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class UserPreview extends React.Component {
  toggle = (user) => this.setState({DropdownOpen: !this.state.DropdownOpen});

  state = {DropdownOpen: false}

  render() {
    let { user } = this.props;
    return (
      <tr className="user">
        <td>
          <Media>
            <img
              alt={`${user.name} avatar`}
              className="avatar d-flex mr-3"
              src={user.url} />
            <Media body>{user.name}</Media>
          </Media>
        </td>
        <td>
          <Dropdown isOpen={this.state.DropdownOpen} toggle={this.toggle.bind(this, this.props.user)}>
            <DropdownToggle caret>
              Admin
            </DropdownToggle>
            <DropdownMenu>
              <DropdownItem>Read</DropdownItem>
              <DropdownItem>Write</DropdownItem>
            </DropdownMenu>
          </Dropdown>
        </td>
        <td>
          <Button color="danger">Delete</Button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    )
  }
}

UserPreview.propTypes = {
  user: PropTypes.shape({
    name: PropTypes.string,
    // TODO: add an url proptype.
    url: PropTypes.string,
  }).isRequired,
};

export default UserPreview;
```

Unlike using a option select, what does one use in dropdown as shown?

**Updated Code:**

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Media,
  Dropdown,
  DropdownToggle,
  DropdownMenu,
  DropdownItem,
  Button,
} from 'reactstrap';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class UserPreview extends React.Component {
  toggle = (user) => this.setState({DropdownOpen: !this.state.DropdownOpen});

  state = {DropdownOpen: false}

  handleChange(e) {
    this.Dropdown({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  }

  onChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({item: e.target.value});
  }

  render() {
    let { user } = this.props;
    return (
      <tr className="user">
        <td>
          <Media>
            <img
              alt={`${user.name} avatar`}
              className="avatar d-flex mr-3"
              src={user.url} />
            <Media body>{user.name}</Media>
          </Media>
        </td>
        <td>
          <Dropdown isOpen={this.state.DropdownOpen} toggle={this.toggle.bind(this)}>
            <DropdownToggle caret>
              Admin
            </DropdownToggle>
            <DropdownMenu>
              <DropdownItem>Read</DropdownItem>
              <DropdownItem>Write</DropdownItem>
            </DropdownMenu>
          </Dropdown>
        </td>
        <td>
          <Button color="danger">Delete</Button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    )
  }
}

UserPreview.propTypes = {
  user: PropTypes.shape({
    name: PropTypes.string,
    // TODO: add an url proptype.
    url: PropTypes.string,
  }).isRequired,
};

export default UserPreview;
```

Comment: can you create a code snippet

Comment: it should open instead of isopen on Dropdown,see the options of drodown here https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#btn-dropdowns

Comment: This is the code snippet and I used those reactstrap buttons. Look here and you can see what I have mirrors these: https://reactstrap.github.io/components/dropdowns/

Comment: I dont get completely what exactly you are looking for?

Comment: To be able to select from the reactstrap dropdown, one of the options. Right now, the dropdown works, but if I click an option, it does not retain or select that value.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the toggle? It looks like you are declaring the bind wrong.

Here is how you would declare the action of the drop down with `toggle={this.toggle.bind(this)}`

this will go outside of render as it's own function

```
toggle (e) {
  this.setState (
    toggle: true
  );
}
```

in addition, to retain that value, you need to add`e.target.value` in your change handler because it is an event that needs to be saved.

Comment: How should it look then? I am not seeing anything wrong with it, but I could easily be wrong here.

Comment: consider writing a change handler and the toggle should be only  `toggle={this.toggle.bind(this)}`
It does look like you are using flux?

Comment: thanks...was wondering that. Is this the way react binds the event? Should this be called within render? Any example you can reference please?

Comment: I could write the example how to handle the event. The change handler should be called outside of render.

Comment: Seems to me, it can be handled with that one of two ways. What I come up with are these:  `handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });`
  }
  or this:
  onChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({item: e.target.value});
  } Just not sure how I can get these to access what it needs. Do I have to apply a name even though this is for one component?

Comment: added update that has two change events in it as I was working with either. Just saw your update as well. Trying to figure which change event is best for my case and how that `(e)` applies and where with what I got.